# Sorting a List of Objects by specific value

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparable

I want to sort a List of Objects (Remarks) by a value contained in another object (DefectClass).

```
public class Remark {
private int remarkId;
private DefectClass defectClass;
}
```

I have a List of Remarks and I'm using this code to sort them by the title of the defectClass :

```
Collections.sort(remarks, new Comparator<Remark>()
            {
                @Override
                public int compare(Remark arg0, Remark arg1) {
                return arg0.getDefectClass().compareTo(arg1.getDefectClass());
                }
            });
```

and this is the Compare to methode in my DefectClass model :

```
public class DefectClass implements Comparable<DefectClass> {
private String DefectClassTitle;
/* Getters And Setters */
    @Override
public int compareTo(DefectClass o) {
    if(o.getDefectClassTitle().equals(this.getDefectClassTitle()))
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

by these codes I want to sort a List of remarks by the Title of the DefectClass of these Remarks ... but At the end I always get the same list with no sorting. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: use either one. 1). `Collections.sort()` with new `Comparator` 2.) `Collections.sort()` for the class that implements `Comparable`.

Comment: use `return o.getDefectClassTitle().compareTo(this.getDefectClassTitle())`. You're never returning `-1` otherwise.

Comment: Check [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) contract, you must return `-1`, `0` and `1`.

Comment: You must create an order with your compareTo method. You must not check for equality but determine which one is greater or lower.

Comment: Use first option if you want to sort on different properties of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of the `DefectClass.compareTo()` method is incorrect, as it should compare the 2 objects and return whether the first one is lower (-1), equal(0) or greater (1) to the second one (and not only indicate whether they're equal as in your case). Assuming `getDefectClassTitle()` is returning `String` I'd implement the method as:

```
public int compareTo(DefectClass o) {
    return o.getDefectClassTitle().compareTo(this.getDefectClassTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not even implement `Comparable`, as you are providing your own `Comparator`.
Use it as follows:

```
Collections.sort(remarks, (r1, r2) -> r1.getDefectClass().getDefectClassTitle().compareTo(r2.getDefectClass().getDefectClassTitle()));
```